# How can I animate an image to spin inside an HTML5 canvas with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I need to animate an object in a way that makes it rotate.  Kind of like a loading game spinner or something but an actual rotation of the image. Not sure if this is actually possible? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why can't you use normal <img /> tag and place the element over the canvas, using position css proprieties and use css animation/transform to rotate the element... http://www.cssrotate.com/

Comment: @NagaHarishMovva That's a good Idea! I may try that if it what I need! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you use normal  tag and place the element over the canvas, using `position` css property and use css `animation`/`transform` to rotate the element...

Check with this URLs

http://www.cssrotate.com/ and http://jsfiddle.net/Ugc5g/1906/

Answer (score 1):

Add this css.You can play with it.

```
.busy-camera-icon {
width:20px;
-webkit-animation:busyIcon 2s linear infinite;
-moz-animation:busyIcon 2s linear infinite;
animation:busyIcon 2s linear infinite;
}
@-moz-keyframes busyIcon { 100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
 @-webkit-keyframes busyIcon { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@keyframes busyIcon { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(360deg); } }
```